# Appendix TOC printed with last chapter partial TOC with titletoc

Tags: memoir, appendices, titletoc

I'm getting a weird behavior with the `memoir` class and the `titletoc` package. I'm printing a partial TOC after each chapter (works perfectly), but for the last chapter, the appendices are also added into that toc. The following code shows a MWE of the problem:

```
\documentclass[openright,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap1}
\startcontents[chapters]
\maxtocdepth{section}
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\small}

\section{chap1sec1}
\section{chap1sec2}

% chap 2

\chapter{chap2}

\startcontents[chapters]
\maxtocdepth{section}
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\small}

\section{chap2sec1}
\section{chap2sec2}

\stopcontents[chapters] % adding this command avoid having appendices in previous partial toc

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix1}
\chapter{Appendix2}

\end{document}
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. How can I avoid having the Appendix1 et Appendix2 in the partial table of content from chapter 2 ?

Thanks for any advice,
Fabian

Comment: Isn't there a `\stopcontents` command? I remember somehow...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Works perfectly. I edited the MWE with right way to do it.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `minitoc` for small tocs inside of chapters/sections...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Wanna write up an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Old, but I've done so :-D

Answer (score 2):

As proposed to the O.P. and to close this question: `\stopcontents[chapter]` will close the `ToC` file and any further sectioning command won't appear in the ToC.

I doubt that `titletoc` and `memoir` should be used together, however.

```
\documentclass[openright,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap1}
\startcontents[chapters]
\maxtocdepth{section}
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\small}

\section{chap1sec1}
\section{chap1sec2}

% chap 2

\chapter{chap2}

\startcontents[chapters]
\maxtocdepth{section}
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\small}

\section{chap2sec1}
\section{chap2sec2}

\stopcontents[chapters] % adding this command avoid having appendices in previous partial toc

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix1}
\chapter{Appendix2}

\end{document}
```